# When pass data between 2 ViewController form valide in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pass data between two navigation controllers. I can this with perform segue method. But I have a problem. My first navigation control has 3 textfields and a button. When click the button push other navigationcontroller. How can I perfom push to other navigationcontrol just when textfields filled. Now I click the button even if textfields empty push other nc. Tahnk you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` and return `true` only when it is allowed to perform the segue, otherwise return false.

`shouldPerformSegue()` is called immediately prior the segue is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Add outlets for the textfields in form, say outlets are named as `textfield1`, `textfield2`, `textfield3`
Implement the following delegate method

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if (textField == textfield3) {
        if self.allTextFieldsAreFilled() { //Check if all textfields are filled
            //Add your push code here
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Add this validating function

```
func allTextFieldsAreFilled() -> Bool {

    if (textfield1.text?.characters.count > 0 && textfield2.text?.characters.count > 0 && textfield3.text?.characters.count > 0) {

        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Be sure to set `delegate` to all the textfields